# Реализовать операции деления для многочлена P(x, sin x, cos x) на основе связанного списка

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++builder, односвязный-список, деление

Многочлен вида P(x, sin x, cos x) на основе связанного списка.
Нужно реализовать в ***C++ Builder*** деление многочлена на другой многочлен (найти целую часть от деления и отдельно найти остаток от деления).

***Структура многочлена:***(примерно такая)

```
struct Node {
    double coefficient; // коэффициент при многочлене
    int x_power; // степень переменной x
    //double sin_coefficient; // коэффициент перед sin(x)
    int sin_power; // степень sin(x)
    //double cos_coefficient; // коэффициент перед cos(x)
    int cos_power; // степень cos(x)
    Node* next; // указатель на следующий элемент списка

    Node(double coef, int x_pow, int sin_pow, int cos_pow, Node* nxt = nullptr) {
        coefficient = coef;
        x_power = x_pow;
        //sin_coefficient = sin_coef;
        sin_power = sin_pow;
        //cos_coefficient = cos_coef;
        cos_power = cos_pow;
        next = nxt;
    }
};
```

Comment: Непонятно зачем тут три разных коэффициента. Он же один.

Comment: ой да, один получается, значит немного другая структура

Comment: В общем случае совершенно непонятно что такое деление многочленов. В случае многочленов от одной переменной есть очевидный вариант деления в столбик, а в вашем случае я даже не знаю что должно получится в результате деления…

Comment: тут нужно реализовать деление уголком, например: 2х^2 +х + cos x делить на 2х целая часть будет х + 0.5 и остаток cos x

Comment: А, например, `2x^2*sin(x) + x + cos(x)` на  `sin(x) + cos(x)`?

Comment: целая часть 2х^2, остаток x+cos x - 2x^2*cos x

Comment: Ну это что-то притянутое за уши. А почему не целая часть `1`, а остаток `2x^2*sin(x) + x - sin(x)`?
В общем для начала нужно однозначно сформулировать как именно устроено эта операция деления.